# Smarty error in plugin

Tags: php, smarty

Can anyone tell me why I get an error with this code?
The error is:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template  "/home/bruce/public_html/shows_rc2/includes/template/theme/basic/theme.tpl"  on line 143 "{plugin->showArtists}" unallowed methode "showArtists" in registered object "plugin" <-- \n  thrown in /home/bruce/public_html/shows_rc2/includes/libs/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 143
```

```html
<?php
class plugin_smarty_artists extends baseplugin {

 public $plugin_info    = 'Smarty artists plugin';
 /**
  * description - A full description of your plugin.
  */
 public $plugin_description = 'This plugin shows random artists.';
 /**
  * version - Your plugin's version string. Required value.
  */
 public $plugin_myversion  = '0.0.1';
 /**
  * requires - An array of key/value pairs of basename/version plugin dependencies.
  * Prefixing a version with '<' will allow your plugin to specify a maximum version (non-inclusive) for a dependency.
  */
 public $plugin_requires = null;
 /**
  * author - Your name, or an array of names.
  */
 public $plugin_author  = 'wmmw';
 /**
  * contact - An email address where you can be contacted.
  */
 public $plugin_email  = '';
 /**
  * url - A web address for your plugin.
  */
 public $plugin_url   = 'http://www.wm-mw.org';

  public $plugin_actions  = array ('install','uninstall','smarty');


  function smartyFunctionshowArtists($params, $smarty) {
    //path to directory to scan.
    $directory = "/home/bruce/public_html/gallery/cr/boimages/";
     
    //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
    $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");
     
    $imgs = '';
    // create array
    foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }
     
    //shuffle array
    shuffle($imgs);
     
    //select first 20 images in randomized array
    $imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 6);
     
    //display images
    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    echo "<img src='$img' /> ";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with the rest of the plugin semantics (perhaps you're not initializing the plugin correctly?), but isn't the actual function name supposed to be declared with a different naming convention?  You're using  camelCase (although the s in showArtists should be capitalized).  But smarty functions expect to be separated by _ underscores.  So I would expect your function name to be : smarty_function _showArtists

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl